# Checking if a variable contains spaces and letters

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to make a program that asks for a name but will reject the input if it doesn't contain letters/spaces. However, it seems to reject spaces as well as numbers and symbols.

```
print("Welcome to the Basic Arthmetics Quiz.")
print("What is your name?")
name=input()
if not name.isalpha()or name not in(str(" ")):
    print('Please only enter letters for your name!')
    while not name.isalpha()or name in(str(" ")):
        v=1
        print('Please enter your name again.')
        name=input()
        if name.isalpha()or name not in(str(" ")):
            v=0
        else:
            v=1
```

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: What are you expecting `name not in(str(" "))` to do, exactly?!

Comment: Your code contains some serious duplication.

Comment: I want it to check to see if there are any spaces in the variable name hence the " ". However im not sure if thats how you do it properly.

Answer (score 0):

This looks an awful lot like homework.

Your test `name not in(str(" "))`, which should be written `name not in " "`, tests whether name is one of `{"", " "}`.

It would be easiest to test the name one char at a time, with a per-char condition like

```
char.isalpha() or char == ' '
```

Combine this with `all` and a generator expression to test all chars of `name`.

The actual implementation, as well as proper code flow (you don't use `v`, you perform the test thrice, and call `input()` twice, all of which is unacceptable) are left as exercise.